# Tkinter: Remove active button highlight

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

How can I remove the dotted black border after a button is clicked in Tkinter (with Ttkthemes)?
[image]

I'm on Windows 10, Python 3.7.9.

There seems to be no uniform way to remove it and I searched across Google and SO with no luck. Thanks.
Here's a minimal example:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

tk = ThemedTk(theme="arc")
tk.configure(background="#f5f6f7")
tk.resizable(0,0)

selectFileInput = tkinter.ttk.Button(
    tk,
    text="Select Input File"
)
selectFileInput.place(x=20,y=60)
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I've never noticed that. Show us a [mcve] please. Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: I've updated the question with more info and a minimal example.

Comment: where is this `inputSelected` this command

Comment: Your example is not complete. I can't run that and reproduce your error.

Comment: Sorry, I removed some unneeded functions. Now it should run without issue. The ttkthemes module is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was to create a dummy button and focus it to remove focus from the button to the dummy button by using `dummy.focus()`

Answer (score 1):

ttk.Button has the keyword argument takefocus this can be set to false and the button does not take focus after it is clicked.

```
ttk.Button(.., .., takefocus=False)
```

Therefore you do not need a hack with a dummy button that takes focus as in the answer.