# Tkinter button remains sunken

Tags: tkinter

I have a button created using the following code

```
    cmd_defaults = ttk.Button(frame, text="Save defaults", takefocus=False)
    cmd_defaults.bind("<Button-1>", self._save_defaults)
    cmd_defaults.grid(row=coords.row, column=1, sticky=tk.SW)

def _save_defaults(self, event) -> None:
    # Save defaults to config
    ...
    result = self.config.save()
    if result == TomlConfig.status_OK:
        messagebox.showinfo(message='Defaults saved')
    else:
        lf = '\n'
        messagebox.showinfo(message=f'Defaults not saved{lf}{result}')
    return None
```

Before pressing the button it appears raised

[image]

But after clicking it remains sunken

[image]

How can I return it to its raised state?

[EDIT]
I am running on Linux (Manjaro with KDE Fusion)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: Remove active button highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752729/tkinter-remove-active-button-highlight)

Comment: No. Sorry. I've added my system to question - don't know if that makes a difference